# ASP.Net Identity 2, Two Factor Security Code timespan

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

We are using 2FA with ASP.Net Identity 2 via email.  This works fine most of the time but in some cases there are delays with the security code getting through to users email, the 6-minute window for the security code then becomes too short.

Is there a way of adjusting this time window for the 2FA code?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to change the validity-timespan in the `UserTokenProvider`.

Try the following in your `UserManager<TApplicationUser>` implementation:

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(
    IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options,
    IOwinContext context)
{
    /* ...create the user store... */ 
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(userStore);

    /* ...all the other config stuff... */

    var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;

    if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
    {
        var tokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));

        // here's what you're looking for:
        tokenProvider.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);  

        manager.UserTokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    return manager;
}
```

Comment: For this to work you also have to change the two factor cookie timeout in the StartUp file like this: UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));